# Perl script, prepend string match with #, insert new string on line below

Tags: perl

I'm trying to update a configuration file using perl, I've come up with a way to read the file in and update key value pairs. However, i'd like to improve it by prepending matches with # and then inserting the string in the line below

Existing script:

```
local($^I, @ARGV) = ("sourcefile");
    while (<>) {
            s,^key1=.*$,key1=value1,;
     s,^key2=.*$,key2=value2,;
     s,^key3=.*$,key3=value3,;
            print;
            close ARGV if eof;
    }
```

Desired result:

```
file before:

    key1=value1
    key2=value2
    key3=value3


file after:

    key1=value1
    #key2=value2
    key2=test
    key3=value3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (/match/) {
  print "#$_";
  s/.../.../;
  print
}
```